# * 3. write a function which returns an object with the suits as its key and its total count as its value // * ans => { heart:1, club:3, diamond:2,}

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const cardData = [
  {
      suit: "heart",
      value: 7,
  },
  {
      suit: "club",
      value: 8,
  },
  {
      suit: "club",
      value: 2,
  },
  {
      suit: "diamond",
      value: 2,
  },
  {
      suit: "diamond",
      value: 5,
  },
  {
      suit: "club",
      value: 10,
  },
];
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: `f=_=>_.reduce(($,{suit:_})=>({...$,[_]:+!!{}+($[_]??!{})}),{});`

Comment: @JaromandaX nice and concise, but I'm curious why you use `+!!{}` for 1 and (+)`!{}` for 0

Comment: @Brother58697 - because it looks cool :p - why make it easy for someone who basically writes a poor question - so, I posted an answer in a comment that is technically correct, but shouldn't be used

Comment: Hahahaha, gotta admit, before opening your reply I was hoping that'd be exactly what you say. Good stuff lmao ;P

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here to get the object where key is the`suit` and `count` is the value

```
cardData.reduce((acc, { suit }) => ({ ...acc, [suit]: (acc[suit] ?? 0) + 1 }),{});
```

```js
const cardData = [
    {
        suit: 'heart',
        value: 7,
    },
    {
        suit: 'club',
        value: 8,
    },
    {
        suit: 'club',
        value: 2,
    },
    {
        suit: 'diamond',
        value: 2,
    },
    {
        suit: 'diamond',
        value: 5,
    },
    {
        suit: 'club',
        value: 10,
    },
];

const result = cardData.reduce((acc, { suit }) => {
    acc[suit] = (acc[suit] ?? 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```